# Magento 2 - Shipping rules for specific products?

Tags: magento2, shipping

This was possible in Magento 1.9 but it doesn't seem possible in Magento 2 table rates to apply rules to specific SKU etc.

Basically, we have products that need a different shipping rule than the rest of the store. The best option I can see is using an extension, the one I've found being: http://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-shipping-suite.html

Are there any suggestions for applying shipping rates per product?

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest to go with free extension if it meets your requirement

https://github.com/rakeshmagento/magento2-shipping-per-product

Please let me know if this will not help.